# When deploy I my code in heroku, it shows "could not find a version that satisfies the requirement python-3.5.2"

Tags: python, heroku

When I deploy my developer's [php](/questions/tagged/php) code in [heroku](/questions/tagged/heroku), it shows

> could not find a version that satisfies the Requirement python3.5.2

How to resolve it?

[image]

Comment: Please provide more information. What have you tried already?

Answer (score 0):

Did you manually add python3.5.2 to the `requirements.txt` file?

This file should be generated only by the Python Package Index, e.g.
`pip freeze > requirements.txt`, and will list your Python dependencies, not the Python runtime version itself.

With Heroku you can specify a particular Python runtime in a text file called `runtime.txt`, e.g. `python-3.6.4` - more information can be found in the Heroku documentation [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-runtimes).

Whilst you *can* use different runtimes, Heroku themselves only support the latest stable releases, which are (at the time of writing) 2.7.14 and 3.6.4.